# Pandas dataframe column with lists of lists of varying lengths to different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': [[['a', 0], ['b', 1]], [['b', 2]], [['c', 1], ['b', 2]]]})
df
```

```
    column
0   [[a, 0], [b, 1]]
1   [[b, 2]]
2   [[c, 1], [b, 2]]
```

Where I don't know which letters exist and the amount of lists in each row varies. My goal is to get it looking like this:

```
     a    b    c
0    0    1    NaN
1    NaN  2    NaN
2    NaN  2    1
```

A first step can be taken using:

```py
df['column'].apply(pd.Series)
```

```
    0       1
0   [a, 0]  [b, 1]
1   [b, 2]
2   [c, 1]  [b, 2]
```

However, a large part of this problem still stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame(dict(l) for l in df.column)

Out[129]:
     a  b    c
0  0.0  1  NaN
1  NaN  2  NaN
2  NaN  2  1.0
```

Comment: Very elegant. An alternative with slightly less chars: `pd.DataFrame(map(dict, df.column))`

Comment: Great! I've now found out that in my data, the lists are actually [value, key] instead of the [key, value] I've described, do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Thanks @rafaelc. Yeah, `map` is more concise. I chose genex/listcomp because I love them :)

Comment: @ThomasW: you mean your data as `[[0, a], [1, b]]` ?

Comment: @AndyL. Yes, I guess I can split `l` as `[reversed(k) for k in l]`

Comment: @ThomasW: just do a dict comp inside instead of call `dict` directly: `pd.DataFrame({y:x for x,y in l} for l in df.column)`

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Pandas 0.25+, you can use `explode`:

```
s  = df['column'].explode()
(pd.DataFrame(list(s.values), index=s.index)
   .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
   .unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
0    a    b    c
0  0.0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful method, I've chosen Andy L.'s method since it is more concise!